# Date Object comparision with primitive value equal to stored time value returns false

Tags: javascript

If you compare primitives with objects, using ==, the comparision makes use of the objects valueOf function, which in most cases returns a primitive bool, string or number.

This can be useful if you wanna compare objects with: `if (customObject == "unique-object-id")` which is similar to, how string instance comparision works and why `new String("foo") == "foo"` results in true, but `new String("foo") == new String("foo")` results in false.

**Example**

```js
class Person {
   constructor(name) { this.name = name }
   valueOf() { return this.name }
}
new Person("John Doe") == "John Doe"; // -> true
```

**RegExp:**

```js
// object with primitive string comparision
new RegExp() == new RegExp().toString(); // -> true
```

The weird part is, how the Date object is compared:

```js
// object with primitive comparision fails here
let now = Date.now(),
  // using the number Date.now() returns to 
  // generate a date object with an value
  date = new Date(now);
date == now; // -> false

// it is larger or equal and smaller or equal
// at the sime time, this only means it is equal...

date >= now &&  // -> true
  date <= now &&  // -> true
  !(date > now) &&  // -> !false -> true
  !(date < now) // -> !false -> true
; // -> true 

// forced comparision works as expected and converting the
// object to its representing valueOf using number conversion
+date == now; // -> true
Number(date) == now; // -> true
new Number(date) == now; // -> true
date.valueOf() == now; // -> true
```

But this works as expected...

```js
const now = Date.now();
new Date() == now; // -> false
// wait for 1ms, no need for async...
while(now == Date.now()); // bad practice but helps on the example
new Date() > now; // -> true
```

The result is as expected, if I use Date object and compare it with smaller or larger numbers. The equal comparision always returns false, if the number used for comparision is equal to the time value stored inside the Date object.

The specification of `Date.now()` or `Date.prototype.valueOf()` does not explain this behavior, neither does [the Section about the equality operator](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-equality-operators) help.

[The section about "What a time value is"](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) describes it as following:

> An ECMAScript time value is a Number, either a finite integer representing an instant in time to millisecond precision or NaN representing no specific instant.

Why does the equal-comparision for a Date object with a primitive fails, if the values are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in the [isLooselyEqual](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islooselyequal) section of the specification.

> x == y
>
> 12. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, BigInt, or Symbol, return IsLooselyEqual(? ToPrimitive(x), y).

And [`ToPrimitive` has](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive):

```
2. If Type(input) is Object, then
  a. Let exoticToPrim be ? GetMethod(input, @@toPrimitive).
  b. If exoticToPrim is not undefined, then
    i. If preferredType is not present, let hint be "default".
    ...
    iv. Let result be ? Call(exoticToPrim, input, « hint »).
```

Look at what happens when `toPrimitive` is called on a Date object with the `'default'` hint:

```js
const date = new Date();
console.log(date[Symbol.toPrimitive]('default'));
```

It gives not a number, but a string, something similar to the format below:

```
Sat Aug 21 2021 09:05:47 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

As a result, the initial comparison of

```
let now = Date.now(),
  date = new Date(now);
date == now; // -> false
```

fails because, when `date` is converted into a string due to `==`, you get:

```
let now = Date.now(),
  date = new Date(now);
someFormattedDateString == now; // -> false
```

`someFormattedDateString == now` clearly fails because `now` is a number, not something that'll be (even loosely) equal to a formatted date string.

In comparison, when you do

```
+date == now; // -> true
Number(date) == now; // -> true
new Number(date) == now; // -> true
date.valueOf() == now; // -> true
```

these all produce `true` because you're converting the date to a *number*, bypassing the `[Symbol.toPrimitive]('default')` (which produces a string as a result) - the number result *does* successfully compare against another number.

- The unary `+` and `Number` coerce the value to a number.
- `new Number` coerces the value to a Number object, which, when compared against a number primitive with `==`, gets the primitive value extracted from the Number object, and results in a successful comparison.
- `Date.prototype.valueOf` extracts the numeric value from the date [as the specification says](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.valueof):

> 1. Return ? thisTimeValue(this value).

```js
console.log((new Date()).valueOf());
```

Comment: Thats great and helps me understanding it. But also opens up other questions. Like why does it behave like this only on equal comparing and not on greater or smaller comparing? But, i should probably open a new question for this.

Comment: See https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islessthan - it converts the result into a number when possible.